# schema.rb not getting updated on rake db:rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have multiple branches each with a migration file. So when I checkout a branch, I do a db:migrate and it would in turn update my schema.rb file.

But, when I checkout another branch and run rake db:migrate, Ideally the changes made my the migration in the previous branch should be removed from schema.rb and the details of the new migration should get into schema.rb

This doesn't happen.

So, I did a rake db:rollback STEP=5, when I checked out a new branch and then did a db:migrate. Even now, I have table details of the migration in previous branch. What I am I doing wrong ? Or is this how Rails behaves?

Answer (score 1):

All performed migrations are saved in table `schema_migrations` (migration timestamp is saved in DB). When you run `rake db:migrate` Rails parses directory `db/migrate` and finds files which are not presented in the table (it compares by timestamp).

Let's you have you have 10 migrations in branch master - `schema_migrations` has 10 records with timestamps. You create a new branch from master `branch_1`, create and run there a new migration. Your table `schema_migrations` has 11 records.

You go back to master and run `rake db:migrate` - Rails will do NOTHING because no new files are found (in `db/migrate`). When you run `rake db:rollback STEP=5` I suppose (I have never checked it) Rails rollback 5 last migrations from branch MASTER. And it's logical because the last migration (made in `branch_1`) doesn't exist in branch master (the file with code exists only in branch_1!). So you can't rollback DB changes made in branch_1 from branch master.

What todo?!
I see several strategies:

1) checkout to `branch_1` and run `rake db:rollback STEP=N` (N >= count of new migrations) (You can rollback more migrations then you performed in this branch). Checkout back to `master` and run `rake db:migrate` (to perform migrations from master)

2) when you have production dump or good seeds.
Drop current DB, load dump (or seeds), run `rake db:migrate`
(As for me it is the simplest way when you have production dump!)

PS Maybe smbd else suggest other way to get correct DB in current branch